# Why can't I connect to my VPN's private DNS servers on some wifi networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I usually connect to the Internet using a VPN (via the `openvpn` client), while also configuring my DNS to use my VPN's private DNS servers as well. But my library's public wifi, I'm only able to connect to my VPN, and not the VPN's private DNS servers.

For example, after connecting to my VPN, the command `nslookup google.com 10.4.0.1` succeeds on my home/work/coffeeshop wifi, but it hangs indefinitely on my library's wifi.

This means that when I use a config like `nameserver 10.4.0.1` in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file, I can get internet at home/work/coffeeshop but I have to change it to something like `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to get internet at the library.

How is this happening? Is it possible that the library's wifi is preventing me from connecting to my VPN's private DNS servers, or is my VPN's DNS server blocking the library's IP address? It seems like only the latter is possible.

Here's some information about my VPN and their DNS specs:
https://airvpn.org/specs/

Note that the library's wifi isn't secured and requires clicking a browser-based login screen to access the wifi. I am turning on my VPN *after* I get past the login screen.

Comment: it could be an address range clash between the libraries network and the VPNs internal address scheme. if the library uses 10.4.0.0/x then the traffic may not be entering the VPN tunnel, but instead going out the physical nic. check your IP route table while connected and see if there are any 10. addresses using an adapter other than your VPN tun adapters. for IP routing to work properly for a VPN, the local LAN, the tunnel network, and the egress/destination network must all have unique address ranges.

Comment: I have similar experiences with another VPN - some place's wifi is just not allowing me to connect the VPN. I guess there are ways for them to block VPN usage.

Comment: @Aganju, yes it is trivial for a network host to block VPNs and really any other protocol they want to, but Op does indicate that the VPN is connecting. The network host will not generally be able to see traffic inside the VPN tunnel, so they can't selectively block it; its all or nothing. if what Op says is correct, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an interesting dive into networking fundamentals - thanks everyone for the help!

I can confirm that Frank Thomas' first comment above is correct. When I'm connected to the library's wifi, where my VPN doesn't work, the IP address assigned to my wifi device is in the 10.x.x.x range. Since my VPN's DNS servers are on 10.4.0.1, there is overlap between the address ranges of the local LAN and my tunnel network. So this is why sending traffic like `nslookup google.com 10.4.0.1` doesn't work - those packets are instead getting sent to the local LAN instead of my VPN tunnel.

I confirmed the address range of the local LAN with the `ip addr` command, which returns something like the following for my wifi interface (`wlp4s0`):

```
...
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:5e:0f:cc:b2:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.184.178.50/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 86323sec preferred_lft 86323sec
...
```

I believe the `inet 10.184.178.50/8 brd 10.255.255.255` excerpt indicates that it's overlapping with my VPN's DNS IP, at `10.4.0.1`.

Note that on other wifi networks, that IP is usually something like `192.168.0.0/x`. I think it's pretty unusual that the library is using a `10.0.0.0/x` CIDR for their local LAN, which is probably why I'm only seeing this issue on the library's network.

Comment: It's a very common range in bigger networks (university, corporate). It's possible that the library's public WiFi is centrally managed as part of a larger network, rather than just being a standalone wireless router in a corner. Set up IPv6 for your VPN for a much lower chance of conflicting with anything.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info! This sounds like a good use case for trying out IPv6 :)